# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.app.api.config.JmsConfig] from ClassLoader.." at springboot startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jms

I am trying to deploy my springboot application on a tomcat server, compiling it in a .war, when starting the project I receive the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.app.api.config.JmsConfig] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: api
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@18769467
]
                at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483)
                at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360)
                at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1632)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:559)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:531)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:243)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:233)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:181)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:156)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
                ... 68 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/ConnectionFactory
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
                at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504)
                at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465)
                ... 84 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
                ... 95 more
```

There are apparently missing JMS dependencies, but the project works when run in IntellJ.

I have been researching a possible solution for a while and all the similar errors I found were solved by adding the dependency that failed to the POM.XML, I added the JMS dependency but the error persists, here I leave my POM.XML for you to take a look at

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>security</name>
    <description>app</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profileActive>local</profileActive>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
                <profileActive>test</profileActive>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
                <profileActive>prod</profileActive>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.16.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-http</artifactId>
            <version>5.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   </project>
```

I greatly appreciate your help!!